# Vertical Layout Group with Images of Different Ratios in Unity 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I create a vertical layout group where all images have the same width (easy) but each has a height that respects its aspect ratio?

I basically just want a vertical wall of elements, some of those elements are images, and each image should look good.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem right now. Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to toggle on Preserve Aspect Ratio on all your images.

If that doesn't help, try this:
For each element in your wall, you can add a Layout Element component, where you can define it's preferred width and height.

You might also have to turn off Child Force Expand on your vertical layout group.

Comment: This does not work for me. Vertical Layout Group will use the Images' preferred height, which is the height it had BEFORE shrinking to the target width, keeping aspect ratio. I also can not statically assign a Layout Element, because the preferred height depends on the width (keep aspect ratio) and the preferred width depends on the container.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but for those finding this while searching:

The **AspectRatioFitter** will adjust the height based on the width of an element, allowing it to fit nicely into a VerticalLayoutGroup. See [this forum post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1445935/preserving-aspect-ratio-for-layout-group-elements.html)